# Seeing WHICH object reference caused a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, exception

When debugging C# with Visual Studio, is it possible to see WHICH object reference on a given line of code caused a NullReferenceException?

I have what seems like an odd situation where, occassionally, when running a debug build of an application from Visual Studio, I will get a NullReferenceException at a certain line.

Visual Studio will pop up the exception assistant box pointing at the line, but none of the 3 object references used on that line are null at that point.

---

The line is:

```
myClassInstance.myMethod(myOtherClassInstance.IPAddressInstance.ToString());
```

Both of my class instances are non-null, as is the IPAddress instance (which has its intended value).

Comment: Sounds like you may have a mismatch between the symbols and the code. Rebuild the debug configuration.

Comment: @John probably not, VS.NET will immediately warn you that the source differs from the loaded module.

Comment: Not so much if there are no debug symbols.

Comment: From above "[...] when running a debug build [...]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling code marked with the `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` attribute, the problem might be in framework code, not on that line.

In any case, do you have a specific example that you could post?

Comment: Updated the question with the line.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful of functions that return null objects.  This got me once and isn't very clear within the debugger.  Check this out:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public int ReturnInt() { return 0; }
}

public FooBar ReturnNullObject()
{
    return null;
}

// Execution code:
int exceptionalInt = ReturnNullObject().ReturnInt();
```

Edit: according to your edit, make sure IPAddressInstance isn't returning null.

Edit: you might want to break the single line into a couple of lines. This should help.

```
var ip = myOtherClassInstance.IPAddressInstance;
var ipString = ip.ToString();
myClassInstance.myMethod(ipString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint at that line at do "step-into" till you get NRE.

No magic, right? Some code try to dereference `null`.

Even if you do smth like `A.Property.Property2.ToString()` as Visual Studio says none of them are null, the problem is then in `ToString()` method, which lies in an assembly, that Visual Studio do not enter in Debug.